# Hibernate not finding book to create table

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, jar

While working on code from internet I am getting error as

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: Book
```

**Book.java**

```
public class Book {

    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public Book() {
    }
//getters and setters
```

**to save data:**

```
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                    cfg.getProperties()).build());


            Session session = sf.openSession();

            session.beginTransaction();
            Book book = new Book("12345767", "Welcome to hibernate","Test");
            session.save(book);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("data saved");
            System.out.println("<------>");
            session.close();
            sf.close();

        }
    }
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection Settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_Class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <!-- Disable the second level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping resource="Book.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Book.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Book" table="books">
        <id name="isbn">
            <generator class="auto" />
        </id>
        <property name="title" />
        <property name="author" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am not able to solve this error,as I have provided everything in my mapping file.Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Error Log clearly says that Hibernate is unable to find the suitable driver for **`jdbc:mysql`**.

**1. Have you added the MySQL JDBC Driver Library in your Project ?**

**2. You have not provided PORT Number in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file on the following line:-**

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
```

Replace this line with

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
```

Comment: Thanks i changed my jar file but now I'm stuck with this error with same code please check the error log

Comment: One more try you can do.. I have doubt in your hibernate mapping file i.e. **`Book.hbm.xml`**.

If your Model class is in some packge. then write the class name after the package name. 

**For Ex:-**  
   `<hibernate-mapping>
       <class name="Model.Book" table="books">
           <id name="isbn">
               <generator class="auto" />
           </id>
           <property name="title" />
           <property name="author" />
       </class>
   </hibernate-mapping>`

Here Model is my Package name (You can have some other name of the package)

Comment: can u tell me how i can use two **xxx.hbm.xml** files for one project like
this is  valid  
sessionFactory=sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("configration.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
and it is not working for new Configuration().configure("configration.cfg.xml").addResource("Employee.hbm.xml")
    .addResource("Department.hbm.xml").buildSessionFactory();
how can i make it to work for two xxx.hbm.xml

Answer (score 1):

Change in `hibernate.cfg.xml` as suggested by rish and use the fully qualified name of class in mapping file and You can try this code to create SessionFactory :

```
 Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
```

Comment: Anand... The Model Class name is **`Book`** not **`Books`**. So he has written correct.

Comment: @Rish is there any way so I can use **StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()**

Comment: One more try you can do.. I have doubt in your hibernate mapping file i.e. **`Book.hbm.xml`**. If your Model class is in some packge. then write the class name after the package name. For Ex:- `<hibernate-mapping> <class name="Model.Book" table="books"> <id name="isbn"> <generator class="auto" /> </id> <property name="title" /> <property name="author" /> </class> </hibernate-mapping>` Here **`Model`** is my Package name (You can have some other name of the package)

Comment: mapping file is OK ,
The error I was getting was **Mapping resource not found** so I added my mapping file in session Factory with **.addResources("map file")** and all error was gone and good thing it is not depreciated BTW Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

after struggling for more then two weeks finally I found the error
unfortunately i wanted to use **standardServiceRegistryBuilder()** and it is still not working (my bad) but instead of using standardServiceRegistryBuilder() one can use **SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addResource("mapping.hbm.xml")
                .buildSessionFactory()** and **is not depreciated even in hibernate 5.0 ** and please correct me if I'm wrong or you get any other better option and thanks Rish